# Parsing HTML for specific <td> tags with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am currently working on a SSL Certificate Enumeration tool that will query https://crt.sh for a specific website, and scrape the results to find sub-domains.  I am using Mechanize to get the results page as HTML, and I need to parse through the response for some specific table data.  Following is an example of one row of results

```
<tr>
  <td style="text-align:center"><a href="?id=47689622">47689622</a></td>
  <td style="text-align:center">2016-10-22</td>
  <td style="text-align:center">2016-05-21</td>
  <td>*.meta.stackoverflow.com</td>
  <td><a style="white-space:normal" href="?caid=1397">C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA</a></td>
</tr>
```

I need a way to pull only the second last  tag, which obviously has no id or class attached to it.  Does anyone have any experience with something similar? If so any tips would be appreciated.  The way I am getting the file from the controller is as follows.

```
domain = params[:domain_name]
@result = "Retrieving domain information from crt.sh\nSee https://crt.sh/?q=%25#{domain} to validate manually\n\n"
host = ENV["https_proxy"][8..-1].split(":")[0]    
port = ENV["https_proxy"].split(":")[2].chomp("/")

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)'
agent.set_proxy(host, port)
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(agent.get("https://crt.sh/?q=%25#{domain}").body, 'UTF-8')
```

I don't have much experience with Nokogiri, as I just started learning Ruby on Rails a month ago and have not needed Nokogiri until earlier today.

Comment: so, do you want  to get contents from `<a>` tags?

Comment: @mr_sudaca No I'm trying to get the <td>*.meta.stackoverflow.com</td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you select the table you can do

```
table.last_element_child.previous
```

which returns the last child and then get the last childs previous sibling.

https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet